# Is the death rate due to police violence between men and women proportional?

Tags: united-states, police, crime, data-sources, gender

According to https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/47814/25402 1 in 2000 men's cause of death is police violence while the corresponding number for women is 1 in 33 000.

> *Risk is highest for black men, who (at current levels of risk) face about a 1 in 1000 chance of being killed by police over the life course. The average lifetime odds of being killed by police are about 1 in 2000 for men and about 1 in 33000 for women.*

**Is that difference proportional? Naïvely, do men commit 16.5 times as many crimes as women? Less naïvely, do men commit 16.5 times as many crimes of types that motivate the police to use lethal violence?**

With the latter I mean that one could motivate that it is reasonable that e.g., armed robbery or school shootings is met with more violence than e.g. shoplifting or speeding on a freeway.

Comment: When the police interacts with people, those people are usually only *suspected* of committing crimes or misdemeanors. A person isn't considered a criminal until a court determined that the person is guilty , and from that point on that person will usually interact with the corrections system, not the police system.

Comment: The type of **suspected** crime is not what determines (or at least it is not what *should* determine) how the arrest happens. No matter how horrible the charges are, the police is only to put you into custody, not to decide or administer punishment, and **proportionate** force is allowed as an answer to resistence/violence to arrest (in particular, lethal force is usually considered valid only for self-defense or defense of other people).

Comment: Which category would a counterfeit $20 be?

Comment: You could guess that people linked to a violent crime would be more prone to react violently to arrest than, say, someone arrested for a white-collar crime, but again, police actions should not be linked to suspected crime, and violence should be minimal. As such, it could be that for the same suspected crime women are less likely to react violently to arrest and, if they do, they pose less of a threat to a police officer. So, even in an unbiased police force a discrepancy in "type of crime"/"death rate" probaby cannot be construed to be significant by itself.

Comment: Note that, depending on the type of crime, the probability of the suspected crime resulting in a police interaction may vary from close to 0 to close to 1.  If you're interested in all crime, you'd have to come up with other methods (such as surveys) to estimate total crime vs. reported crime vs. crime with a police interaction.

Comment: This is a highly misleading question.  First, you have to separate out the numbers killed by police because they were actually committing crimes from the number that were just being harassed, or simply in the way, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_of_Justine_Damond  Second, police (being mostly male) are likely to harass women differently from men.  You might compare the male/female ratio of people coerced into sex by police.

Comment: @jamesqf The question is perfectly reasonable if we're gathering information on that harassment.

Comment: I suspect a large part of the difference is that males are far more likely to resist arrest, and more likely to resort to violence, and higher degrees of violence, then women when resisting arrest.  IE  situations that warrant the legitimate use of force are more likely to occur when arresting males then females.  Well that and likely there is also a gender bias playing a role, since males are *perceived* to be more dangerous, Police may underestimate the threat of a female resisting arrest or overestimate the threat of a male when judging degree of force required to subdue the individual.

Comment: **'proportional' to *what*, exactly**? To their representation in the general population? Or the subset that interact with the police? incl. bystanders and witnesses. Or people who are suspects/victims of a crime? or only violent crime? or any crime where police use force? or any crime where police use lethal force? You need to define which.

Comment: @dsollen Are you sure about that? There are many times as many male murderers or bank robbers as there are female murderers or bank robbers but that doesn't mean that the women actually robbing banks are less violent than men. In fact, they are even further out in the normal distribution than their male colleagues, possibly meaning they are more violent than male bank robbers.

Comment: Statistics for resisting-arrest would seem helpful.

Comment: Related question with a focus on race instead: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/54017/is-the-frequency-of-lethal-police-interactions-between-black-and-white-americans

Comment: I hear rich people [steal more](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2019/nov/04/wealthy-people-shoplift-rob-steal-why) than the poor. So in this line of misguided questions assuming that crime justifies killings by police: shouldn't the police kill more rich people?

Comment: @Fizz Misguided? Reality is not black and white. One of the main tasks for the police is to bring suspects as unharmed as possible to court.

Comment: @jamesqf There is a bias against men though. [Prof. Starr's Research Shows Large Enexplained Gender Disparities in Federal Criminal Cases](https://www.law.umich.edu/newsandinfo/features/Pages/starr_gender_disparities.aspx#:~:text=After%20controlling%20for%20the%20arrest,the%20racial%20disparity%20that%20Prof.) and [Policing Women: Race and gender disparities in police stops, searches, and use of force](https://www.prisonpolicy.org/blog/2019/05/14/policingwomen/) are just a few articles that cover this.

Answer (score 11):

The FBI Uniform Crime Reporting (UCR) Program, the latest year for which statistics are available at time of writing being 2018, gives a [breakdown by sex](https://ucr.fbi.gov/crime-in-the-u.s/2018/crime-in-the-u.s.-2018/tables/table-42) for arrests made during the year.

In particular, for arrests in general, 5,684,385 males were arrested, compared to 2,126,700 females. This represents a ratio of about 2.67 to 1.

With respect to 'crimes of types that motivate the police to use lethal violence', this is a little harder to broadly define, as clearly every arrest is different, but if we use the FBI's definition of violent crime - "offenses of murder and nonnegligent manslaughter, rape, robbery, and aggravated assault" - the figures are 313,411 males arrested compared to 82,854 females, a ratio of about 3.78 to 1.

The only crimes which had a ratio of male arrests to female arrests greater than 5 to 1 were Robbery (5.62), Murder and nonnegligent manslaughter (7.19), Weapons; carrying, possessing, etc. (9.71), Sex offenses (except rape and prostitution) (13.41), and Rape (30.51).

The only crime for which more women were arrested than men was Prostitution and commercialized vice, with 80% more women (15,243) arrested than men (8,456).

Note that arrests are obviously not equivalent to actually committing or being found guilty of the offense, but are probably a better metric of interaction with police.

Comment: This answer has the major unstated assumption that arrests are proportional to crimes committed, which is certainly not the case.  Not only are many arrested people innocent, there are also large numbers of crimes for which nobody ever gets arrested.

Comment: @gerrit see the last sentence

Comment: The last sentence covers being arrested and being not guilty, it doesn't cover the much larger category of being guilty but not being arrested

Comment: @gerrit arrests would seem to me to be the best indicator of interaction with police, however. Perhaps my 'and', should be an 'or' though.

Comment: True, arrests would seem a reasonable indicator of interaction with the police, in particular such interactions which may turn violent.  It's rather the question that is somewhat poorly phrased here.

Comment: Do arrests in this context also include people who are killed in an arrest attempt?  (This is probably also biased towards men, but since presumably far more arrests than killings occur it might not skew the overall statistics that much.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman According to the FBI, the statistics are collated from "law enforcement agencies submitting 12 months of arrest data for 2018". Presumably, this then includes occasions where suspects were arrested and then died in custody, but not those who were killed in an arrest attempt. The annual number of people killed by US police seems to waver around 1,000, however, so although a huge number in real terms, doesn't make much of a dent in the statistics above.

Comment: @gerrit If you look at the "Clearances" section of the linked source, there are additional data tables with (for example) percentage of known offenses that resulted in an arrest.  These percentages turn out to vary quite a bit between different types of crime and between different population groups, which makes this rather difficult to analyze.

Comment: The ideal statistic would be something like "violently resists arrest": is there a stat for people charged with resisting or running?

Comment: @DewiMorgan That runs into the issue of false charges, which are almost certain in wrongful deaths caused by police.

Comment: @MatthewWells I presume that #killed will be far smaller than #charged, so that shouldn't affect the stats much.

Comment: @Matthew Wells: There are also instances of people killed by police who are not being arrested, or in any way suspected of any crime at all.  E.g.    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_of_Justine_Damond https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_of_Jeremy_Mardis

Comment: @jamesqf Excellent point, yes.

Comment: This is a bad answer because (1) it assumes (for the first five paragraphs) that arrest rate is the same as crime rate. The final paragraph mentions police interactions but doesn't even attempt to ground this with any data. Here's a recent DoJ report: [Contacts Between Police and the Public, 2015](https://www.bjs.gov/content/pub/pdf/cpp15.pdf#page=2) published in 2018. (2) It ignores any possibility of police bias based on gender. I would hope recent events might cause one to question how likely it is that police are not-biased. See the linked DoJ report for why this might be relevant.

Comment: [Policing Women: Race and gender disparities in public stops, searches, and use of force](https://www.prisonpolicy.org/blog/2019/05/14/policingwomen/) shows the difference between interactions of police-initiated interactions of suspected men and women. [Prof. Starr's Research Shows Large Unexplained Gender Disparities in Federal Criminal Cases](https://www.law.umich.edu/newsandinfo/features/Pages/starr_gender_disparities.aspx#:~:text=After%20controlling%20for%20the%20arrest,the%20racial%20disparity%20that%20Prof.) shows how there is bias against men, which was 6 times bigger than racial bias.

Answer (score 2):

A 2018 report from the Department of Justice outlines ["Contacts Between Police and the Public, 2015"](https://www.bjs.gov/content/pub/pdf/cpp15.pdf) (published 2018). The report notes

> Overall, a higher percentage of males (22%) than females (20%) experienced police contact (table 1). This was driven by a higher percentage of police-initiated contacts among males (12%) than females (9%)

Table 1:

```
Demographic       U.S. population     Any contact        Police-initiated    Resident-initiated
characteristic     age 16 or older                           contact             contact
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Male*                  122,968,400 | 27,038,300  22.0%  | 15,339,100  12.5%  | 12,537,300  10.2%
Female                 130,619,000 | 26,431,000  20.2 † | 12,076,800   9.2 † | 14,523,000  11.1 †

*Comparison group.
†Signifcant diference from comparison group at the 95% confdence interval.
```

Arrest counts are not proportional to police interaction. Using the arrest counts for the same year (2015) by gender ([male](https://ucr.fbi.gov/crime-in-the-u.s/2015/crime-in-the-u.s.-2015/tables/table-39), [female](https://ucr.fbi.gov/crime-in-the-u.s/2015/crime-in-the-u.s.-2015/tables/table-40), [both summary](https://ucr.fbi.gov/crime-in-the-u.s/2015/crime-in-the-u.s.-2015/tables/table-42) ) shows 6,067,584 male arrests and 2,238,335 female arrests.

To answer the question

> Is the death rate due to police violence between men and women proportional?

Then, the incidence of police interaction by gender is not proportional to

> The average lifetime odds of being killed by police are about 1 in 2000 for men and about 1 in 33000 for women.

---

Additional considerations:

- Police bias based on gender is not considered
- The above table shows annual police contact, it is not a direct comparison to an individual's "lifetime odds" as police contact may vary with age

Comment: Off topic but related study: https://www.prisonpolicy.org/blog/2019/05/14/policingwomen/ , notes "Women make up an increasingly large share of arrests" 27% up from 16% in 1980. And "Use of force: Nearly doubled for men since 1999, but more than quadrupled among women". And "Street stops: Significant racial disparities among men, but not women" but notes "Arrests during stops: Significant racial disparities among women, but not men". And finally "Use of force during stops: Rates of Black women similar to white men; Black and Latino men most likely to experience force"